# Manhwa where the mc changes back into her pre-isekai appearance and the male lead still loves/accepts her

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember the mc and the male lead (I think there were other people too) in a cave, and the female mc's changes to her appearance before she got isekai'd, with  some glowing aura around her, and she hides behind a big boulder because she doesn't want the male lead to see her but the male lead says he'll accept her no matter what she looks like, something along those lines.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Why does her appearance revert?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?